# EDI ISA and GS ID Generation

Tags: edi

My question may sound very novice.I am new to EDI format as have to work on it for first time.

We are applying YRC Trading partner profile to get EDI data.

They are asking for ISA receiver ID and qualifier

Prod ID and  Qualifier

GS Test ID

GS Prod ID

After searching on google thoroughly i found DUNS id can be used as ISA receiver id and 01 can be its qualifier.But nothing found much about the PROD ID ,GS TEST ID AND PROD ID.

See the URL for PDF file  http://www.yrc.com/files/pdf/820_tpp.pdf

My query is how to identify or generate ISA PROD ID and its qualifier and GS TEST AND PROD ID.

On google while searcging i only found people asking where to find ISA and GS but no concrete solution for starter on EDI.

If i dont wants to use DUNS number as ISA ID then how to generate ISA ID and its qualifier.

Please Help.It can be helpful to me and any new programmer working on EDI for first time.

More info needed to answer my query :

YRC Freight supports versions 3050, 3070, 4010, 4020 and 4030.
YRC Freight provides for direct connections via AS1 (SMTP), AS2 (HTTP), or FTP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

several options.
Look at the qualifiers that can be used and you will get an idea of what you can use as ID.
Eg phone number, GLN, DUNS.

Normally the ID in GS is the same as in ISA.
It is not uncommon to use same ID in production and test (but take care of not having test messages in the production and vice versa).

Comment: To elaborate, you want to make sure your ISA and GS ids are both globally unique because of the way the functional acknowledgement (997) works; that acknowledges at the functional group (GS/GE) level so that's why you need the unique id in the GS segment.

Comment: ISA and GS IDs not necessary same in all cases. Here is good explanation: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9dedf201-a133-4e55-8ecb-8697a431e88b/can-isa-and-gs-sender-and-receiver-ids-be-different?forum=biztalkediandas2

Answer (score 18):

The interchange qualifier is used to describe the interchange identifier. For example, if we have a qualifier 12, it says that the interchange identifier is a phone number. Here's the list of all the valid identifiers in EDI (X12 - V004010)

01 - Duns (Dun & Bradstreet)

02 - SCAC (Standard Carrier Alpha Code)

03 - FMC (Federal Maritime Commission)

04 - IATA (International Air Transport Association)

08 - UCC EDI Communications ID (Comm ID)

09 - X.121 (CCITT)

10 - Department of Defense (DoD) Activity Address Code

11 - DEA (Drug Enforcement Administration)

12 - Phone (Telephone Companies)

13 - UCS Code (The UCS Code is a Code Used for UCS Transmissions; it includes the Area 
Code and Telephone Number of a Modem; it Does Not Include Punctuation, Blanks or Access Code)

14 - Duns Plus Suffix

15 - Petroleum Accountants Society of Canada Company Code

16 - Duns Number With 4-Character Suffix

17 - American Bankers Association (ABA) Transit Routing Number (Including Check Digit, 9 Digit)

18 - Association of American Railroads (AAR) Standard Distribution Code

19 - EDI Council of Australia (EDICA) Communications ID Number (COMM ID)

20 - Health Industry Number (HIN)

21 - Integrated Postsecondary Education Data System, or (IPEDS)

22 - Federal Interagency Commission on Education, or FICE

23 - National Center for Education Statistics Common Core of Data 12-Digit Number for Pre-
K-Grade 12 Institutes, or NCES

24 - The College Board's Admission Testing Program 4- Digit Code of Postsecondary Institutes, or ATP

25 - American College Testing Program 4-Digit Code of Postsecondary Institutions, or ACT

26 - Statistics of Canada List of Postsecondary Institutions

27 - Carrier Identification Number as assigned by Health Care Financing Administration (HCFA)

28 - Fiscal Intermediary Identification Number as assigned by Health Care Financing Administration (HCFA)

29 - Medicare Provider and Supplier Identification Number as assigned by Health Care Financing Administration (HCFA)

30 - U.S. Federal Tax Identification Number

31 Jurisdiction Identification Number Plus 4 as assigned by the International Association of Industrial Accident Boards and Commissions (IAIABC)

32 - U.S. Federal Employer Identification Number (FEIN) 33 National Association of Insurance Commissioners Company Code (NAIC)

34 - Medicaid Provider and Supplier Identification Number as assigned by individual State Medicaid Agencies in conjunction with Health Care Financing Administration (HCFA)

35 - Statistics Canada Canadian College Student Information System Institution Codes

36 - Statistics Canada University Student Information System Institution Codes

37 - Society of Property Information Compilers and Analysts

AM - Association Mexicana del Codigo de Producto (AMECOP) Communication ID

NR - National Retail Merchants Association (NRMA) - Assigned

SN - Standard Address Number

ZZ - Mutually Defined

Comment: I had the same question about ISA ID and Qualifier. Following kaushik0033's suggestion, i used "12" for a qualifier, and a unique 10 digit phone number for both ISA ID and GS ID. Amazon Vendor Central accepted it. I would vote up kaushik0033's answer if i had enough reputation for that :)

Comment: I'm attempting to parse an EDI document. I know that it is X12 format, but I do not know how to determine the X12 version - such as 4030, 4010, etc. Do you have any tips on how I can find this? Searching the .txt file has revealed many matches, but difficult to know if they're false positives

Comment: Edit: found the version number using this tool: http://www.liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad/

Answer (score 1):

Many of the things in the ISA and GS headers are used for routing data.  The ISA is an outter envelope that has some high level information about the entire interchange and all documents included within it.  Within this envelope can be many groups of different document types.

The GS/group is an envelope that can contain multiple transactions (STs), that is multiple purchase orders, or in the case of YRC, perhaps multiple 204 Load Tenders.

The ISA usually routes the data to your system, and then you will use the GS within your system to identify which process to kick off depending on who sent the data, what type of transactions are contained in it, etc.

So as far as the IDs go, if you want to use separate test IDs to help you identify how to process the data, you can use the test ID, and then when you go live, you can switch over to the prod ID.  It's mainly all up to you to pick what works best in your case.

Many times, identical IDs are used for test as in production.   Many other times, identical IDs are used, but they will have a T at the end for test.  This is what I would choose to do in your case.  If your production ID is 00000112 (or something similar), use 00000112T for test.

Answer (score -2):

A DUNS number could be used as your ID with the right qualifier which is telling the other side what is that number that you have used as your ID. 
Try talking to get an EDI consulting from one of the companies out there who can help you with this task.
One of the companies that you can look at is Amosoft EDI Services ([www.amosoft.com](http://www.amosoft.com)) they might be able to help you. Good Luck!